# What is the noun for the act of zipping?

Tags: nouns, conjugation

For some words there is a noun for the act of doing. For example, "deletion" is the act of deleting, "omission" is the act of omitting, "summation" is the act or process of forming a sum. Is there such a word for "zipping"? I'm asking from a programming context, so I'm talking about zipping a file. That may inform the question, since many of these verbs have an object or lack thereof as a result.

Here are a few examples of the types of sentences I'm thinking of:

He had disrupted the class, and the students did not appreciate the disruption.
After a deletion, the program will return to its previous state.
The reformation of the group was mainly due to Sarah's newfound zeal for scrapbooking.

The analogous usage would be "disrupt"->"disruption", "delete"->"deletion", and "reform"->"reformation".

Comment: Strictly speaking, *compression*.

Comment: What's wrong with "zipping"?

Comment: Hm, I like it! @ michael.hor257k that sounds about right, even though technically it's not the same base word. @Hot Licks I can't use zipping because I'm not referring to the act while it's happening

Comment: It is unclear what you are looking for. How is 'zipping', the gerund, not what you want. Please edit your question to clarify at length, adding at least two example sentences with a slot where you want to put your requested word.

Comment: By induction, Ziption

Comment: You seem to have an overly narrow definition of the word "zipping." Words ending in "-ing" can refer to many things. They don't just refer to "the act while it's happening." For example: "Painting" can refer to an act in progress ("He was in the process of painting a portrait"), but it can also refer to an activity in general ("Painting is an enjoyable activity," "Painting is an important form of art"), or even the result of an action ("A painting hung on the wall").

Comment: Well, since zipping is a form of fastening, I'd suggest "fastenation".

Comment: @sumelic, maybe. I think "painting" is a good example of the kind of word I'm thinking of. "The painting of the building gave a new freshness to its outdated architecture." Then you could use zipping, and that would probably be correct.

Comment: @Mitch I added some examples

Comment: @HotLicks, I'm sorry, I think you're right and "zipping" works

Comment: @BarryL It is unclear in your examples where 'zip' would be analogous. Could you specify?

Comment: @HotLicks Dude...

Comment: @Mitch okay, I changed it to add the analogous usages. I think "scrapbook"->"scrapbooking" may also be analogous, but I don't feel confident enough about it to put it in there.

Comment: I think you need to provide some ACTUAL sample uses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [compression at techtarget.com](http://searchstorage.techtarget.com/definition/compression), defined as

> Compression is a reduction in the number of bits needed to represent data.

It is the word for zipping a file.

Comment: That seems correct for my uses, but I'm still curious about whether such a word exists for the word "zip"

Comment: Top results and popular dictionaries return nothing but *zipping*.

Comment: Yeah, it's so disappointing!

Answer (score 3):

Zipping and compression aren't the same.  You can zip without compression.  Zipping refers to combining files into a container file; compression is optional.  The general term for combining files in this way is "archiving", so the noun would be **archive** (which also happens to be a verb).

"Archiving" is the act of putting files in an archive, which is [*a file that contains one or more files in a compressed format.*-(webopedia)](http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/A/archive.html)

Note that archiving also has other meanings related to saving files.  Although this particular definition refers to files in a compressed form, that is common, but not a necessary condition of archiving.  There is also an inherent "compression" of space requirements due to saving wasted space associated with minimum and incremental units of space used for storing files.

"Zipping" is often used as a generic synonym for archiving, but "zip" actually refers to a specific archive file format that was one of the very early ones for personal computers and became extremely popular. (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_%28file_format%29 for more background.)